# Pattern Recognition Problem

Tags: pattern-recognition

I have the following questions:

Suppose we have the following chart, which represents the relationship between   faculties and types of objects; for example CTE represents Computer Technologies, and  the intersection between CTE and Wood says that at the CTE faculty there are 56 types of wood.

My question is: Can I use this table as a tool for PCA analysis?

Or can I represent these data in  matrix form and perform a principal component analysis from this data table?

I need it for pattern recognition rate problems.

I know Matlab well and linear algebra as well; I just need advice.

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: it  is something like statistical analyse  of different type of persons     ,their characters  and so on

Comment: Homework, in other words?

Comment: to  be honestly  i dont know what is  meaning of homework in this case,but it is  related with my  article  researching

Comment: I don't know what to say, you can use any table for PCA analysis, but whether it is meaningful or not depends on the data and what you are trying to do with it. The answers to your two questions are yes and yes, but these answers are somewhat meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this table for PCA, but the data points would give you a more refined idea and use a covariance matrix since the data is on the same scale

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UUxIXU_Ob6E) is a video explaining PCA usage for finding patterns similar to your case